# display list using DefaultListModel and JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I am trying to display a list of items using DefaultListModel and JList but my window is empty. What is the error?

see code:

```
    public class ViewInventoryInterface extends JFrame {
    private Inventory theInventory; // reference to back end
    private InventoryUPCIterator iter;
    private DefaultListModel dlm;
    private JList list;
    private JScrollPane scroll;

    public ViewInventoryInterface(Inventory theInventory) {
        this.theInventory = theInventory;
        iter = theInventory.inventoryUPCIterator(); //returns an iterator for the inventory
        dlm = new DefaultListModel();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            dlm.addElement(iter.next().toString());
        }
        list = new JList(dlm);
        scroll = new JScrollPane(list);
        setTitle("Inventory");
        setSize(400, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A first problem might be that you're not adding anything to your frame. Use  `getContentPane().add(...)` etc. to add your scroll pane to the frame.

Depending on the layout manager you might need to have different additional parameters but with the default `BorderLayout` just adding should work.

Comment: thanks, now it is showing the keys but not the items that the keys reference. How can I correct this?

Comment: from Java5 and higher isn't required call for ContentPane, simple add(JComponent) +1

Comment: @trs It looks like you're only adding the keys to the `DefaultListModel`. You'd either have to create a different string representation or create your own list model (you might subclass `DefaultListModel`), add the keys and the items and provide your own `ListCellRenderer` implementation in order to display anything else than keys.